# How to download PDF after fadeout the success message?

Tags: php, email, magento, controller

I am using a form to submit email and name to the user. After submitting the form email triggered and success message displaying. Success message fade-out after 10 seconds i.e. fine.  Now I want to download a pdf also after fadeout success message.

I am achieving this via action.

I am using below code:

```
<form class="brochure brochure_1" method="post" id="custom_contact_form" action="http://example.com/contact/index/contact" onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="myForm">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" class="input-text required-entry toname" value="" name="toname"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFromUrl(); ?>" name="submiturl" class="submiturl" />
        </div>
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <span><input type="submit" value="Download" /></span>
    </form>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (email == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

jQuery('.success-msg').insertBefore(jQuery( ".breadcrumbs" ));
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery('.success-msg').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    });
</script>
```

Comment: write your code below   jQuery('.success-msg').fadeOut('fast');

Answer (score 0):

Replace the document ready like this,

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery('.success-msg').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds
window.location.href = href; //causes the browser to refresh and load the requested url, Put the url to download pdf here.
    });
```